My canister doesn't launch, trying to read the docs about buffer & the tutorial
I'm doing the motokobootcamp.com chapter 1 and trying this simple code, the canister doesn't run on Gitpod.
import Buffer "mo:base/Buffer";
actor {

    let name : Text = "deFiSport";
    var manifesto : Text = "deFiSport is  a DAO that rules few canisters & dApps allowing young sportsmen & sportwomen to earn money thanks to their performances, image & more."
    let goals : Buffer.Buffer = Buffer.Buffer<Text>(0);

    public shared query func getName() : async Text {
        return name;
    };

    public shared query func getManifesto() : async Text {
        return manifesto;
    };

    public func setManifesto(newManifesto : Text) : async () {
        manifesto := newManifesto;
        return;
    };

    public func addGoal(newGoal : Text) : async () {
        goals.add(newGoal);
        return;
    };

    public shared query func getGoals() : async [Text] {
       return Buffer.toArray(goals);
    };
};

I tried to :

Copy-Paste the solution, it doesn't work

Watching the tutorial

Read the docs, especially about Buffer


This is what returns the terminal.


-------------------------- Edit --------------------------
The problem was a semi-column that I missed to the variable manifesto.
The thing is now a new error occured.


I see that this line does not end with a semicolon.
var manifesto : Text = "deFiSport is  a DAO that rules few canisters & dApps allowing young sportsmen & sportwomen to earn money thanks to their performances, image & more."
Also
Verify your github access is working.
Check ability to:
login to github;
access files on github from your local machine (e.g. git clone).
if you haven't done so, "Create GitHub SSH keys"
Another path:
Setup a local motoko build environment and build without deploy.
https://internetcomputer.org/docs/current/developer-docs/getting-started/install/#installing-dfx-via-dfxvm
Once you have a solution that builds, test it in the "Motoko Playground - DFINITY" by creating a project there and copy/paste your source code.  Build the canister there.  Submit your cansister id as per the assignment.

What is the error on Gitpod? Any printscreen?
The code is correct (at least am not spotting anything).

I edit the message to post what the terminal returns.
